# Compilation error "Can not set the content of ListView as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttributte" in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors

I basically want the ListView cells to have auto height, and that's what I came up with:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MovieDbApp.UI"
             x:Class="MovieDbApp.View.MoviesPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="0">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding PosterPath}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding DisplayGenre}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This should be simple enough, but now I'm getting that compilation error ans I have no idea what it means as there's no `ContentPropertyAttributte` in ListView, or at least none that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`

```
       <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="0">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding PosterPath}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayGenre}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I'm stupid like that sometimes... Thanks a million!